# SQL mangement user error

Tags: sql-server-2008

When i am creating users in SQL management studio i create them under the server name and then i create them under the database but when i try to log on using the user name and password i cant. getting erro saying

### > TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to LAPTOP-RED\SQLEXPRESS.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=233&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the suggested solution from the help link is:

> User Action
>
> Use the SQL Server Surface Area Configuration tool to allow SQL Server
>   to accept remote connections. For more information about the SQL
>   Server Surface Area Configuration Tool, see Surface Area Configuration
>   for Services and Connections.

Which is what you have to do. By default the SQL Express Server isn't configured to allow remote connections.

Answer (score 2):

hi I faced same issue in MicroSoft sql server 2008.
this error occurs while user limit exceeded, as you have set max connection to 1 and if someone is already logged in (or using any webpage which access your server) then it will not allow anyone to access  directly or indirectly. to solve this issue simply follow following steps:

1. stop all web services.
   [image: Stop IIS or all webservices/websites]
2. open services.msc using RUN and ****restart sql server** and do not start any service which uses your sql server, so that you will be able to log in using sql server management studio.
   [image: Restart services]
3. now open sql server management studio and click on **New Query** button.
   [image]

   4. It will ask for user name and password use your login name and password.
      [image: Log in]
4. run these scripts one by one `sp_configure 'user connections', 0
    go`
   6.`reconfigure with override`
   [image: reconfigure sql script]
5. after this restart your sql server it will show a confirmation message click on OK. 
   [image: restart sql server]

Bingo

It works. please don't forgot to vote ;-)